Error "ESM integration proposal for Wasm" is not supported currently
I'm working on a Shopify app built with the latest version of Shopify and using the Firebase Admin SDK for backend operations. I've encountered an issue where, whenever I change routes within the app, it reloads a new session and redirects to the home page. Additionally, I'm seeing the following error in the console:
"ESM integration proposal for Wasm" is not supported currently. Use vite-plugin-wasm or other community plugins to handle this. Alternatively, you can use .wasm?initor.wasm?url. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#webassembly for more details. at LoadPluginContext.load (file:///home/test/test/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BzOvws4Y.js:47494:13) at PluginContainer.load (file:///home/test/test/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BzOvws4Y.js:48968:17) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) at async loadAndTransform (file:///home/test/test/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BzOvws4Y.js:51762:22) at async viteTransformMiddleware (file:///home/test/test/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BzOvws4Y.js:61776:24)

Relevant Code Snippet:
import firebase from "firebase-admin"; const app = firebase.initializeApp({ credential: firebase.credential.cert(firebaseConfig), }); export default app;

I'm using Vite as the build tool.
The error mentions WebAssembly (Wasm) integration, but I'm not directly using any Wasm in my project.
This issue causes my app to reload the session on every route change, which is not the expected behavior.
Has anyone else experienced this issue with Firebase Admin and Vite, particularly in a Shopify app?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
enter image description here
I'm also attaching vite.config.js and package.json =>
vite.config.js =>
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

if (
  process.env.HOST &&
  (!process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_URL ||
    process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_URL === process.env.HOST)
) {
  process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_URL = process.env.HOST;
  delete process.env.HOST;
}

const host = new URL(process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_URL || "http://localhost")
  .hostname;
let hmrConfig;

if (host === "localhost") {
  hmrConfig = {
    protocol: "ws",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 64999,
    clientPort: 64999,
  };
} else {
  hmrConfig = {
    protocol: "wss",
    host: host,
    port: parseInt(process.env.FRONTEND_PORT) || 8002,
    clientPort: 443,
  };
}

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: Number(process.env.PORT || 3000),
    hmr: hmrConfig,
    fs: {
      allow: ["app", "node_modules"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    remix({
      ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*"],
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
  build: {
    assetsInlineLimit: 0,
  },
});


package.json =>
{
  "name": "shopify_app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production remix vite:build",
    "dev": "shopify app dev",
    "config:link": "shopify app config link",
    "generate": "shopify app generate",
    "deploy": "shopify app deploy",
    "config:use": "shopify app config use",
    "env": "shopify app env",
    "start": "remix-serve ./build/server/index.js",
    "docker-start": "npm run setup && npm run start",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "shopify": "shopify",
    "graphql-codegen": "graphql-codegen",
    "vite": "vite"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^18.20 || ^20.10 || >=21.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hello-pangea/dnd": "^16.6.0",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.7.1",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.11.1",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.7.1",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.7.1",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^4.1.2",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^12.0.0",
    "@shopify/shopify-app-remix": "^3.0.2",
    "@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage": "^3.0.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "firebase": "^10.13.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.4.0",
    "isbot": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "^2.7.1",
    "@shopify/api-codegen-preset": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.40.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.6.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "extensions/*"
  ],
  "trustedDependencies": [
    "@shopify/plugin-cloudflare"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "undici": "6.13.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "undici": "6.13.0"
  },
  "author": "sanket"
}


So far i have tried to downgrade the firebase version but it did not resolve the issue.
I think the issue is related to vite configuration, so if any export can help, it will be greate!
